# Coroutine is resetting material and changing rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a really weird bug that I can't pinpoint. I have 2 weapons - an assault rifle and a burst rifle. I use a coroutine for the BR, but it removes the bullet's material and fires from the wrong angle.

[AR video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJtaJeI_XSg)
Full AR code: https://pastebin.com/eHNCQ4Yf

```
void Shoot()
{

    GameObject BulletNew = Instantiate(Bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    BulletNew.GetComponent<Bullet>().sender = gameObject.transform.root.gameObject;

    Destroy(BulletNew, 2);
}
```

[BR video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7sUalRPh64)
Full BR code: https://pastebin.com/wqqdrPbv

```
void Shoot()
{

    GameObject BulletNew = Instantiate(Bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    BulletNew.GetComponent<Bullet>().sender = gameObject.transform.root.gameObject;

    Destroy(BulletNew, 2);
}

public IEnumerator FireBurst()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < burstSize; i++)
    {
        GetComponent<soundManager>().PlaySound();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(bulletDelay);
         Shoot();
    }
}
```

However, when I unparent the weapon it [works perfectly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5m-9hvFvMs).

Both use the same references, I've triple checked. When I comment out the coroutine for the BR and just use the regular shoot function it's completely normal. I rid of recoil, same result. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't getting the gun, it's getting the character:

```
BulletNew.GetComponent<Bullet>().sender = gameObject.transform.root.gameObject;
```

I don't know what Bullet.sender does here, but I would guess you're getting the transform.forward or something, but you're not passing the gameObject, which I'm assuming would be the gun itself, but instead you're passing gameObject.transform.root.gameObject, which is the root object in the project hierarchy, which is why it works when you detach the gun - in that case the gun IS the root object.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Unfortunately that code is just for an old kill feed I had. I commented it out and nothing changed.

Comment: @James okay but are you sure? There's nothing in the code you provided (that I saw at least) that does anything about changing materials or raycasting, so if passing the wrong game object isn't the issue then your issue probably isn't in this code. As I say that though I'm wondering if using the coroutine is somehow causing your Bullet logic to fail, but you haven't provided the Bullet class so I can't really tell. But to my main point - no material access or raycasting or collision detection, etc. in this code.

Comment: Hey @Chuck , I agree it’s really weird. I removed the bullet and just started instantiating a sphere. Same exact issue, nothing to do with the bullet code. I might package up the scene and send it around to see what’s up with it.